# Calculating Standard Deviation with If in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a dataset with two columns. One label and one number. Using `sumif` and `countif`, I managed to calculate the average of each label in groups. Now, I am trying to do the same with Standard Deviation but I have a problem:

`=STDEV.P(IF($A$2:$A$625129=F4,$B$2:$B$625129))`

This is the formula I use, where A column is the column with the labels, B with the numbers and F4 is one of the label groups. The result is 0. I do the same for every label group and all of them are 0. Any idea what is wrong in the formula?

Edit: After the comment, I tried to apply the formula as an array one and it almost worked. Now, the only problem is that the cell F4 is static whereas I want it to be dynamic (F5, F6, F7 etc) for every cell in array formula.

Comment: Have you ensured you've committed that as an array formula?

Comment: @XORLX You are right. I applied it as an array formula but the F4 cell is static. Do you know how I can do it dynamic for all the cells?

Comment: You need to put the formula in a single cell first, then apply CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER....and then copy down

Comment: Great! That works. I, first, chose the whole area and applied the array formula there. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the sake of an answer (courtesy @barry houdini):

> You need to put the formula in a single cell first, then apply CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER....and then copy down