# Excel - Create Summary Statistics for previous date range (previous month, previous year, etc) using dynamic date field

Tags: excel, date, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a worksheet that calculates summary statistics (think mean and standard deviation) for the previous X timeframe (previous week, previous month, previous quarter, etc) dynamically, based on a cell for the start date.

I have it setup such that I had 2 columns of data; column A is the date for a given observation and column B is the number itself. I'd like to be able to type in a date to my date field and have my summary statistics automatically update.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

[image: Worksheet setup example]

Comment: SUMIFS, AVERAGEIFS, standard dev is a bit more complex but doable.

Comment: How do you do standard deviation? SUMIF and AVERAGEIF seem obvious enough but I'm getting tripped up on the syntax of the conditional statement. Could you show me an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245252/calculating-standard-deviation-with-if-in-excel