# Use excel to get a standard deviation per item number

Tags: excel, standard-deviation

To keep it simple, I have an excel spreadsheet that sorts the data by item number and release number. I can have 5 of the same item number, each with different volumes of released quantities. I want to get a standard deviation of each part number using the total release values over a 3 month period. Is there a way to do this that doesnt require manually inputting a standard deviation function for each block of release numbers per part id?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245252/calculating-standard-deviation-with-if-in-excel perhaps as inspiration.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some sample data and the expected outcome. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to enhance your question.